# Getting a 500 error after proposing and backing a tag on Stackoverflow Documentation Beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Whenever I try to visit the Documentation Tag backing page now (`aframe`), the 500 error persists.

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/aframe

Comment: What was the URL you were trying to get to? Because I can get to http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/aframe no problem...

Comment: Your attempt to commit through a null ref, and the subsequent visit did as well. Something's definitely broken there. Don't have the code in front of me, though, since I'm technically on vacation. :) I'll fix it up on Monday if other folks on the Docs team don't beat me to it.

Comment: Looking into this now.

Comment: Thanks, to answer Mike, that URL gives me a 500 after trying to back it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a null ref issue happening after a user had committed to a tag proposal.

A fix has been pushed out.

Thanks for reporting!